# Catch an invalid HTTP request method globally

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, logging, httprequest

I would like to restrict my Web API endpoints to certain HTTP methods, such as GET and POST. I have searched the internet and I found out that you can add either `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]` above your method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password) {
    // do login stuff
    return View();
}
```

Now I want to test if the example above with `[HttpPost]` really works so I use postman to send a HTTP request to my Web API. I fill in the URI and set the method to GET. The response I get is as follows:

```
{
    "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
}
```

I'm able to verify that adding `[HttpPost]` prevents me from using HTTP GET requests.

What I would like to do now is log the event whenever an user tries to sent GET requests when the application is expecting POST, and vice versa. I could implement something for every single method but this would take a lot of time and it wouldn't be easy to make changes once it's been implemented. So I would like to filter it globally or something.

For example something like:

```
class MethodRequestFilter : SomeGlobalMethodFilter
    {
        public override void Filter(SomeRequestContext requestContext)
        {
            if (usedRequestMethod.isNotValid == true)
            {
                //implementation for logging
            }
        }
    }
```

But ofcourse I haven't been able to find this yet within the libraries of .Net. How can I log the event globally whenever a user tries to make a request that isn't a supported method?

Greetings,

Damien.

Comment: So, what do you want do after catching the request? just logging?

Comment: I would like to log the event by sending an alert to my [OWASP AppSensor](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AppSensor_Project)  REST server.

Comment: Then you can achieve it to create your base(custom) controller which will inherit from api controller and all other controllers will inherits from base controller, once user request for the particular method the call it from your base controller and check if there any error..

Comment: Wait  a minute, you mean, you don't want to use [HttpGet] and [HttpPost]?

Comment: @Div I want to to use only HttpGet and HttpPost, but it differs per request. In my example of the login request i only accepted HttpPost and tried to use a HttpGet on it, which ofcourse shouldn't work. Whenever I have applied either a [HttpGet] or [HttpPost] to a request, I want to log every other request that a malicious user tries to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to using common base controller, to implement you need to add one base controller which would inherited from `ApiController`

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {            
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // or if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) 
            {
                //log here 
            }
            return response;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return await InternalServerError(ex).ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        }            
    }
}
```

Now, let's assume that you're having `ValuesController` and `Login` method and it supports only POST, here your all other controllers inherit from `BaseController` instead `ApiController`

```
public class ValuesController : BaseController
{ 
  [HttpPost]
  public void Login([FromBody]string value)
  {
  }
}
```

So, once you call your login method, it'll call BaseController method first and you will get response there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the user [div](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4753489/div) I was able to solve my problem by using a base controller that implements logging. These are the steps that I had to take:

1. Create a new controller class called `BaseController` and inherit `ApiController`:
2. Override the `ExecuteAsync` method from `ApiController`:
3. Add an implementation for logging in the catch clause
4. Inherit the new `BaseController` in every controller class that you would like to have logging functionality.

The code that I used in my implementation:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);

            return response;
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException ex)
        {               
            if (ex.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed)
            {
                //Logging implementation
            }
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(ex.Response.StatusCode, ex.Message);
        }   
    }            
}
```

If there is any way to make my code better, please let me know :)